# Does Allah hate the playboys?

Tags: halal-haram, allah, non-muslim, non-muslim-countries

In USA it is cool to have sex with girls to use them as sex objects, then throw them away and replace them with some other girl who is younger and prettier. People call them studs, players, heartbreakers, etc.

Does Allah punish heartbreakers?

Because it is cool for men to cheat on your wife. It is a double standard for women. If women does what men do is bad.

And to those women who were used then left, will Allah give them justice and all that good stuff whether they were Muslim or not?

I looked up the word "forever" on urbandictionary.com

It means " i will love you till someone better comes along."

The one who wrote that definition, was he  sinful?

Is it haram to write those definition on that website?

Please Muslim brothers give me your answers.

I live in the USA and it is hard and sad. Hardly anyone is good. I think all men are evil. I just need my faith to be restored. Thanks.

Comment: one thing I would like to point out is: If you read the Quran or listen to it, you will find the answers they are clearly written there!

Comment: Sorry. Even when I read Quran I do not know how to apply it in real life.

Comment: @user15732 I suggest you visit a nearby Islamic center, they will help you there.

Comment: I am too shy to say in person. I need to remain anonymous.so I cannot. Can you give me an answer?

Comment: You've been asking the same question again and again. Many people are ready to help you, but please note that you're wasting a lot of people's efforts by forcing them to answer you're duplicates. What research have you done? Did you look other related questions?

Answer (score 2):

> Does Allah punish heartbreakers?

I guess it depends, if its in relation to the scenario you've mentioned in your question then of course it is wrong to take advantage of others vulnerabilities to fulfil any aims or goals

This hadeeth refers to how wrong it is to take advantage of others weakneses (in the hadeeth the weakness was being scared):

> “The companions of Muhammad (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
>   him) said that they were travelling with the Prophet (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him), and a man among them fell asleep.
>   Some of them got a rope and tied him up, and he got scared. The
>   Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:
>   ‘It is not permissible for a Muslim to frighten another Muslim.’”
>   (Narrated by Abu Dawood).

You can imagine the other wrong actions one may take to deceive a person (lying...) which we know are clearly haram

> He (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “The Muslim is
>   the brother of another Muslim, he does not wrong him, let him down or
>   look down upon him. Taqwa (piety, awareness and fear of Allah) is
>   here” – and he pointed to his chest three times – “It is sufficient
>   evil for a man to look down upon his Muslim brother. Every Muslim is
>   sacred to another Muslim, his blood, his property and his honour.”
>   (Narrated by Muslim)

In regards your point quoted below:

> And to those women who were used then left, will Allah give them
>   justice and all that good stuff whether they were muslim or not?

One thing to point out here is that we know that people will be judged individually but we don't know what judging criteria God has in place unless he reveals that to us, and it is only God who knows whats in a persons heart, however we know that God is just:

> … if you do judge, judge between them justly. Allah loves the just.
>   (Surat al-Maida, 42)

In regards your query quoted below, the only case I think a word may be Haram is if it is made up for a purpose to insult any thing to do with our beliefs(god, prophets) OR if the word is a profound word such as swearing words

> I looked up the word "forever" on urbandictionary.com It means " i
>   will love youvtill someone better comes along."

about what you said below:

> I live in the USA and it is hard and sad. Hardly anyone is good. I
>   think all men are evil. I just need my faith to be restored.

That's really not true because there are a lot of people out there with sincere intentions, I know that it is hard where you live (I feel your pain) and every thing seems to be sexualised these days perhaps thats why you may feel this way, but for a piast/God fearing person will never do any of that because he knows that he has to answer to God for his actions, just pray to God that you will find someone suitable and hold on to patience and Iman

> (2:153) O you who have believed, seek help through patience and
>   prayer. Indeed, Allah is with the patient.
>
> “…Indeed, the patient will be given their reward without account.”
>   [az-Zumar 39:10].

Comment: Well, in urban dictionary. I know that word "forever" does not have swear words. But I heard speaking without knowledge is haraam, right? Or being biased in your opinion, is wrong? Right? That is why, I hate that website.

Comment: Yes I think being biased is definitely wrong and of course it is always good to base you thinking on  knowledge, logic and reason. what site are you talking about!

Comment: Ugh. It is urbandictionary.com. i hate it. But it is bugging me because that is how humans think. Do you think shaytan is controlling that site?

Comment: @user15732 God knows best, I hate slang and invented words of any kind and refuse to even learn what slang words mean (its a waste of time)!

Comment: Thanks. I love your comment. I need to stop looking up slang words. I have slight OCD. I have a bad habit of curiosity. I am going to follow you by refusing to learn. Thanks.